# If $A,B$ and $C$ are the interior angles of a triangle, then what is the maximum value for $\sin(A)\cdot\sin(B)\cdot\sin(C)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

If $A,B$ and $C$ are the interior angles of a triangle, then what is the maximum value for $\sin(A)\cdot\sin(B)\cdot\sin(C)$?

I couldn't think of a specific direction to start the solution with.

Comment: If you want to use multivariate calculus (as tag suggests), notice that $C=\pi-A-B$ and by simple rules you have $\sin(C)=\sin(A+B)$, reducing to minimizing  $\sin(A)\cdot\sin(B)\cdot\sin(A+B)$ with two variables.

Comment: @Sil I'm studying multi-variable calculus at university right now. We were on the topic of Lagrange multipliers when this question was given. Should I somehow think of a way to apply that?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible. You want to maximize $f(A,B,C)=\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)$ under condition $g(A,B,C)=A+B+C-\pi=0$, so the Lagrangian is $L(A,B,C,\lambda)=f(A,B,C)-\lambda g(A,B,C)$. It is also useful to use $A,B,C \in (0,\pi)$.

Comment: See my answer for a bit more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, you seem to be interested in multivariate calculus application, especially Lagrange multipliers. Here is a sketch of such an approach.

Writting down what we want to maximize and under which condition, we arrive at Langrangian
$$
L(A,B,C,\lambda)=\sin A\sin B\sin C-\lambda (A+B+C-\pi).
$$
Now you need to evaluate stationary points of this function. You can restrict yourself for a moment to closed region $(A,B,C)\in[0,\pi]^3$, since in closed region the function attains both its minima and maxima (in $(0, \pi)$ you would find it has only one stationary point, it might be tricky to argue it is actually a maximum).

If you calculate these stationary points correctly, you should obtain four points $(A,B,C)$, namely $(0,0,\pi)$, $(0,\pi,0)$, $(\pi,0,0)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3})$. Simple evaluation shows that $(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3})$ gives maximum $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}$, and the other points give same minimum $0$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

By AM-GM

$$\sin A \cdot \sin B \cdot \sin C \le \left(\frac{\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}{3}\right)^3$$

with equality for $\sin A=\sin B=\sin C$.

Comment: I know that AM=GM when a=b=c, but is it necessary that AM be maximum when a=b=c in all questions (not just this one) ?

Comment: @Sunaina Here I’m just suggesting to use the known result for the sum.

Comment: I have just started learning about inequalities so apologies if I sound dumb     : ), but as far as I understand it's necessary that the AM be maximum when a=b=c. We have to prove the AM is maximum separately, right?

Comment: @Sunaina Exactly we can prove for the sum of sines separetely.

Comment: okay thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

We know that $\ln\circ\sin$ is concave in $(0,\pi)$, therefore

$$\ln (\sin A\sin B\sin C)=\ln\sin A+\ln\sin B+\ln\sin C$$
$$\le 3\ln\sin\left( \frac{A+B+C}{3}\right)=3\ln \sin\frac\pi3=3\ln\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$
So $$\sin A\sin B\sin C\le \frac{3\sqrt 3}{8}$$