# Find maximum value of $\sin(A) \sin(B) \sin(C)$, where $A, B,$ and $C$ are angles of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was doing this problem that requires to prove that $P≤\frac{3\sqrt{3}R^2}{4},$ where $P$ is an area of a triangle and $R$ is the radius of its circumscribed circle.

I started with the law of sines $\frac{a}{\sin(A)}=\frac{b}{\sin(B)}=\frac{c}{\sin(C)}=$2R, and $P=\frac{abc}{4R},$ so I got
$4P=8R^2\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C).$

so the problem comes down to proving that
$\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)≤\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}.$

Comment: Hint: use Jensen's inequality; $\ln\sin x$ is convex.

Comment: Sorry, I mean concave.

Comment: Why the closing proposal ? There is work in this question !

Comment: Hint:  $\sin(\frac{A}{2})\sin(\frac{B}{2})\sin(\frac{C}{2})\le\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841570/maximum-value-of-sina-cdot-sinb-cdot-sinc

Answer (score 3):

This is easy if you can use calculus, because the only restriction on $A, B, C$ is that they must add up to $\pi$ (apart from domain restriction). This means the partial derivatives must all be equal, otherwise you could, say, take a little bit off of A and give it to B to increase the product.
Suppose (wlog) $A$ and $B$ are not equal. Then, the partial derivatives are

$\cos(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)$ and $\sin(A)\cos(B)\sin(C)$

Obviously $C$ isn't 0 when you're maximising the product, so $\cos(A)\sin(B) = \sin(A)\cos(B)$

$\cos(A)\sin(B)-\sin(A)\cos(B) = 0$ turns into $\sin(B-A)=0$ by the sum of angles formula. But this can only happen when $B-A$ is a multiple of $\pi$. So as they're between $0$ and $\pi$, it must be that $B-A=0$. Similarly, the other pairs of angles must be equal. SO it must be an equilateral triangle.